# Can crawlers find content loaded using body's onLoad() and ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, seo

I've created a HTML page where I'm using body's onLoad callback, fetching content from a Servlet via Ajax call and sending it to a div (the content contains info about books - each book as a table containing title, tags, author etc.).

Now I wonder when I submit this page to a search engine, will the bot be able to crawl this ajax content?

Any help/suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No. Search engines, in general do not crawl Ajax content. The only exception is [Google's crawlable ajax proposal](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) which you apparently did not implement. [But its use is discouraged anyway](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs). So your website is definitely not search engine friendly.

What you should have done is built the site to work without JavaScript and then used [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) to make it work *better* with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Just for information, the Google's crawlable ajax proposal is also supported by at least Bing and Yandex (principal russian search engine).